# What would be the best way to filter part of the timestamp?

Tags: sql, oracle

For example, I have a **TIMESTAMP** field and a record is something like `'2021-04-23 14:17:46'` in my database, and I want to find the records that start with `'2021-04-23'`, that is a part of the TIMESTAMP, in SQL. What would be the best way to filter part of the timestamp?

And the other way around? If I have something like '2021-03-04' and I want to find all the timestamps that are yyyy-MM-dd HH: mm: ss

Comment: Why on earth do you store timestamp values as **string**? User proper `DATE` or `TIMESTAMP` data type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your parameter is a valid date string, use date arithmetic. For example

```
-- parameter
with prm as (
   select  '2021-04-23' pd from dual
),
-- sample data
tbl(Code, Dt) as (
  select 'c1',  TIMESTAMP '2021-04-23 12:17:46' from dual union all
  select 'c2',  TIMESTAMP '2021-04-24 14:17:46' from dual 
)
--
select tbl.*
from tbl
cross join prm
where dt >= TO_DATE(prm.pd, 'YYYY-mm-DD') and dt < TO_DATE(prm.pd, 'YYYY-mm-DD') + 1
order by code, dt
```

Answer (score 1):

The simple way is to `TRUNC`ate the timestamp and compare it to a literal:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
WHERE  TRUNC( timestamp_column ) = DATE '2021-04-23'
```

This may be simple but its not the best solution as Oracle will not use any index on the `timestamp_column` and will perform a full table scan; to use an index you would need to create a function-based-index on `TRUNC( timestamp_column )`.

The better way, although slightly more complicated, is to compare on a range of values using a `TIMESTAMP` literal:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
WHERE  timestamp_column >= TIMESTAMP '2021-04-23 00:00:00'
AND    timestamp_column <  TIMESTAMP '2021-04-23 00:00:00' + INTERVAL '1' DAY;
```

or, using `DATE` literals:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
WHERE  timestamp_column >= DATE '2021-04-23'
AND    timestamp_column <  DATE '2021-04-23' + INTERVAL '1' DAY;
```

If you want to compare to a string, rather than a literal, then use `TO_TIMESTAMP`:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
WHERE  timestamp_column >= TO_TIMESTAMP( '2021-04-23', 'YYYY-MM-DD' )
AND    timestamp_column <  TO_TIMESTAMP( '2021-04-23', 'YYYY-MM-DD' ) + INTERVAL '1' DAY;
```

or, to remove the time component:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
WHERE  timestamp_column >= TO_TIMESTAMP( SUBSTR( '2021-04-23 14:17:46', 1, 10 ), 'YYYY-MM-DD' )
AND    timestamp_column <  TO_TIMESTAMP( SUBSTR( '2021-04-23 14:17:46', 1, 10 ), 'YYYY-MM-DD' ) + INTERVAL '1' DAY;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select dttm_col
from table
where to_date(dttm_col) = '2020-01-20'
```